# Error while add new element in CSS

Tags: css, intellij-idea

In a grails project I had a css. I tried declared a new attributes in css like below and i get error

[image]

I had some suggestion from IDE IntelliJ as below

[image]

and the error gone.
Can anyone tell me why the error comes and gone? What does Add to custom html tags means? In which file I can see this changes?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a selector without any special type like class (using `.` period) or id (using `#`) etc. They are treated as an html tags type.

Eg

```
div{
   color : red;
}
```

Above rule denotes all divs in your html.

Editors / ide's (intelij-idea in this case) comes with built in support for understanding all types of selectors and html tags. But when you add a unknown html tag inside your css it throws an error.

There  might be case that you may have created cutsom html tags. (You can do that and set css for them). So it gives you option to set whatever the unknown html tag you are using to be identified as custom html tag. As soon as you do that the new tag becomes known and error goes away.

I don't have information about where this information is stored when you set custom html tags. It must be set internally or on the project level.

Comment: Is there a way I can find this custom tag declaration file? I try project search for keyword kbdTrs but find nothing new

Answer (score 0):

`kbdTRS` is not a HTML tag, so intellij-idea tells you that it doesn't exists (it triggers an error). 
intellidj-idea is a clever IDE, so it offers you some options to correct this error. 
Since `kbdTRS` is not a known HTML Tag, intellidj offers you to add it to your **custom html tags**. 
Intellidj thinks that you have created custom-tags and that you want to apply CSS rules to this tags.

[Here is an article about custom tags](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)